# Count of 2 columns by GROUP BY and catx giving different outputs

Tags: sql, sas

I have to find distinct count of combination of 2 variables. I used the following 2 queries to find the count:

```
select count(*) from 
(   select V1, V2 
    from table1
    group by 1,2
) a
```

```
select count(distinct catx('-', V1, V2)) 
from table1
```

Logically, both the above queries should give the same count but I am getting different counts. Note that

- both V1 and V2 are integers
- Both variables can have null values, though there are no null values in my table
- There are no negative values

Any idea why I might be getting different outputs? And which is the best way to find the count of distinct combinations of 2 or more columns?

Thanks.

Comment: What's returned by `count(distinct cat(V1, '-', V2))` query?

Comment: Which version of SQL (MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, etc) is this?

Comment: @MarkBannister I am not really sure. I am working in SAS environment and I think this is a variant of MySQL. But the logic shouldn't vary with the version of SQL, right?

Comment: @raina77ow `cat` doesn't work in SAS environment. It's `catx`.

Comment: @Macbook Really? Then what's [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002257060.htm)?

Comment: @Macbook, the function catx isn't supported in many flavours of SQL - there are other functions / operators used to concatenate values, dependant on SQL.

Comment: SAS SQL is its own variant of SQL.  CATX in this case, at least, is a SAS function, not anything having to do with SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SAS log gives the answer when you run the first sql code.  Using 'group by' requires a summary function, otherwise it is ignored.  The count will therefore return the overall number of rows instead of a distinct count of the 2 variables combined.
Just add count(*) to the subquery and you will get the same answer with both methods.

```
select count(*) from 
(   select V1, V2, count(*) 
    from table1
    group by 1,2
) a
```

Answer (score 2):

Use distinct in the subquery for the first query..
When you do a group by but don't include any aggregate function, it discards the group by.
so you will still have duplicate combinations of v1 and v2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GROUP BY doesn't work that way in SAS. You can't use it to remove duplicates unless you have an aggregate function in your query. I found this in the log of my query output -

> NOTE: A GROUP BY clause has been discarded because neither the SELECT
>   clause nor the optional HAVING clause of the associated
>   table-expression referenced a summary function.

This answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

you can ignore the group by part also and just add a distinct in the sub-query. Also the second query you wrote is more efficient